# bitcoin testnet daemon stuck

Tags: testnet

I am running bitcoin testnet daemon for development, but lately I have trouble with starting the daemon. Blockchain is downloaded and it seems that everything runs fine till

> init message: Verifying blocks...
>
> Verifying last 288 blocks at level 3

then it seems stuck or takes hours before doing anything. Interesting is that restarting the daemon helped me couple times and daemon started in several minutes as usual. In this time i cant obviously use RPC commands. 
I dont have trouble starting mainnet daemon. Anybody has any idea what might cause and how to fix this overly long verification?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help the site by marking answers as accepted if they are correct and address the question so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

I found out that long verification at start of bitcoin daemon can be caused by large number of keys generated and stored in wallet.dat. in my case >1600 keys can take more than 30min of verification.